# Find child coordinates and pass them further?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, parent-child

I have a list of objects and a script to show one object randomly. How I can receive the coordinates of the active objects' child, so I can pass them further? I wanna world coordinates be written into x,y, and z.

[image]

Here is the script:

```
public GameObject[] objects;
    public int objNumTrunk;
    public int objCountTrunk = 0;
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float z;
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        objNumTrunk = Random.Range(0, 3);
        objCountTrunk = 0;
        while (objCountTrunk < 3)
        {
            objects[objCountTrunk].SetActive(false);
            objCountTrunk += 1;
        }
        objects[objNumTrunk].SetActive(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a new variable and store the reference of objects[objNumTrunk]. i am assuming that you already have a script on the child objects.
now, whenever OnMouseDown will be called, the reference will be updated and you can receive the coordinates of the active objects' child

Example:

`public GameObject selectedObject;`

Inside your OnMouseDown() at the very end

`selectedObject = objects[objNumTrunk];`

Now you can access the coordinates using
`selectedObject.GetComponentInChildren<ChildScript>().coordinates`

Comment: I do not have a script on the Child. Could I receive only a world position of the Child? Smth like (1.0,0.5,0.0) and pass it as x=1.0, y= 0.5, z= 0.0 ?

Sorry for the Dumb question, I am a noobie in C# yet

Comment: yes, `selectedObject.getchild(0).transform.position`

PS: this is not the ideal way as there are many other ways to implement the logic